# postgres LISTEN connection termination

Tags: postgresql

We are using postgres LISTEN/NOTIFY mechanics together with node-pg

```
        let sql = 'LISTEN ' + o.name
        
        db.query (sql)
        
        db.on ('notification', async e => {
```

Sometimes after long app inactivity time our notifications stop to deliver

What exactly is going on undercover node-pg LISTEN?

What is OK state for this situation? Shouldn't be there active connection from app to db?

How we can debug this?